# constructor do not enter a function C#

Tags: c#, function, call

i have code. the constructor should enter the `GetItems` function but when i place breakpoint, it simply do not stop.

what is the problem?

```
namespace Storehouse {
    public partial class MainForm : Form {
        public MainForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
            var a = GetItems(fILEToolStripMenuItem);

        }

        public IEnumerable<ToolStripMenuItem> GetItems(ToolStripMenuItem item) {
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem dropDownItem in item.DropDownItems) {
                if (dropDownItem.HasDropDownItems) {
                    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem subItem in GetItems(dropDownItem)) {
                        yield return subItem;
                    }
                    yield return dropDownItem;
                }

            }

        }
}
```

Comment: where have you placed the break point?

Comment: Because of using `yield` and `IEnumerable`. Suggest you try `var a = GetItems(fILEToolStripMenuItem).ToList();`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you're using [yield](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx), it means deferred execution, so you need to enumerate your variable `a`, like this:

```
var a = GetItems(fILEToolStripMenuItem).ToList();
```

You can also use `ToArray()`, whatever, you simply need to enumerate your `IEnumerable`.